# Algorithm to check if variable changed since start of the loop PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, variables, loops, compare

```
//Initialize
i=0;
foreach(runs 8 times) {
  if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i + 3;
  } else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
    //Do nothing with i
  } else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i -4;
  }

  if(what condition do i put here to check if $i changed from the start of the loop?) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1
  } else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
  }
}
```

Hey guys, i'm sure this is obvious, but I'm having a hard time with this algorithm, and each time I need to make sure that $i isn't the same as it was at the start of the loop and do Action 1 or Action 2 based on that distinction.

For iteration 1, I could put if($i == 0) {, but then on iteration 2 and 3 that has the potential to fail.

Comment: add another counter you increment too and not only $i?

Comment: Where do you increment `$i` since you have `i=0;` as the first line of your loop?

Comment: write your exact code here

Comment: At the starting you are initializing the `$i=0` so easily you can check the value of $i is zero or not.

Comment: why will it fail? $i is reset on every iteration. and since the if is inside the for loop, it should work fine

Comment: Hey guys, I should have put the initialization outside of the loop, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use another variable and save the value of $i in that one if it has changed. Then you can always compare that variable to $i when you check for a change.

I don't think you should have the $i inside the loop though.

```
$previousValue = null;
$i=0;
foreach(runs 8 times) {
  //Initialize
  if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i + 3;
  } else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
    //Do nothing with i
  } else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i -4;
  }

  if($previousValue == $i) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1
  } else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
    $previousValue = $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, figured it out because of this!

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the state at the beginning and check it afterwards:

```
foreach(runs 8 times) {
  //Initialize
  i=0;
  oldi = i;
  if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i + 3;
  } else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
    //Do nothing with i
  } else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i -4;
  }

  if(i != oldi) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1
  } else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$previous = 0;
foreach(runs 8 times) {
//Initialize
$i = 0;
if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i + 3;
} else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
//Do nothing with i
} else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i -4;
}


if($i != $previous) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1
} else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
}
$previous = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ichanged = false;
i=0;
foreach(runs 8 times) {
  //Initialize

  if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $ichanged = true;
    $i = $i + 3;
  } else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
    //Do nothing with i
  } else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $ichanged = true;
    $i = $i -4;
  }

  if($ichanged == false) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1        
  } else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
    $ichanged = false;//RESET for next iteration
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple, just add one more variable inside the loop and initialise it to `i` value every time the loop iterates

try this code :

```
//Initialize
i=0;
j=0;
foreach(runs 8 times) {
  j=i;
  if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i + 3;
  } else if (some other condition that sometimes happens) {
    //Do nothing with i
  } else if(some condition that sometimes happens) {
    $i = $i -4;
  }

  if(j==i) {
    //nothing changed, do action 1
  } else {
    //Else something changed and do action 2.  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since only one of the cases will be evaluated, why not just call the function that does something when $i changes immediately?

```
$i = 0;
foreach(/*runs 8 times*/) {

  if(/*some condition that sometimes happens*/) {
    iChanged($i, $i + 3);
    $i -= 3;
  } elseif (/*some other condition that sometimes happens*/) {
    iDidntChange($i);
  } elseif(/*some condition that sometimes happens*/) {
    iChanged($i, $i - 4);
    $i -= 4;
  } else {
    iDidntChange($i);
  }

}
```